# Run Visual Studio 2010 with two commands

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to run Visual Studio 2010 with two commands:

```
devenv.exe /nosplash

devenv.exe /safemode
```

How can I run Visual Studio 2010 with both commands? Meaning, I need to run an instance where both commands are executed with them.

How do I do this with Visual studio 2010?

Comment: `devenv.exe /nosplash /safemode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, simply type...

```
devenv.exe /nosplash /safemode
```

...and all should be well. (Tested and works fine on my set up.)

Answer (score 1):

Run it as:

```
devenv.exe /nosplash /safemode
```

It seems to work OK when I run it.